# Continue Ajax call for table data till the text not found

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy, gsp

I've list of data like...

```
| Coloumn1 | Coloumn2 | Coloumn3  |
|----------|----------|-----------|
| val1     | val2     | val3      |
| val1     | ' '      | val3      |
```

The above table I've on form submit, now after some time I found the value of Coloumn2 instead of ' '/BLANK, So I want to put it into the table without reload the page.

I've following code structure...

myInstance.gsp

```
<tbody id="myInstanceTData">
<g:each in="${myInstanceList}" var="myInstance">
<tr id="${myInstance?.id}">
        <td class="align-center zoomout">
        <td class="align-center">${myInstance?.text?:"N/A"}</td>
        </td>
        <td class="align-center" style="color:${myInstance?.objectColor}">
            <g:if test="${myInstance?.object}">
                ${myInstance.object}
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                ${"Second Analytics"}<br>${"In-Progress"}
                <img src='../assets/transfer.gif' style="height: 18px;"/>
            </g:else>
        </td>
        <td class="align-center" style="color:${myInstance?.objectColor}">${myInstance?.confidence?:"N/A"}</td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
</tbody>
```

Currently I've written that `${"Second Analytics"}<br>${"In-Progress"}` here I require call to Controller action till I didn't receive any text for the same.

Thanks...

Comment: Using datatables with server side processing would be ideal here https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html, you can use a periodic refresh of the table e.g. https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried below code. Working fine for me.

```
function fetchColumn2() {
  setInterval(loadColumn2, 3000,id);    
}

function loadColumn2(id){
//Make ajax call and get response
$.ajax({
        url:URL,//URL to action in controller
        data: {id:'1'},
        success: function(resp){
            console.log(resp.id);
            console.log(resp.column2);
            var column2Val = resp.column2;
            if(column2Val != ""){
                //TODO: Set value to your table data
                clearInterval(this);
            }                
        }
    });
}
```